# How can I find the innerText and outerHTML of an webpage element using the inspect window on Chome and/or Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, web-inspector

I'm trying to manually find the innerText and outerHTML of buttons on websites by right-clicking them and pressing inspect, but I don't know where I can find these properties. The screenshot below shows what I see when I right-click --> inspect the 'compose' button in Gmail. [Screenshot of inspect window on Firefox after selecting 'compose' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQ1w.png)

Any straightforward solution (for Firefox and/or Chrome) would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could find it by right-clicking the element and pressing inspect and after that, by right click on the tag there is an option  `Edit as HTML`.

I think that would solve your problem.

[image]